# Ignore an unknown XML element node in GSOAP

Tags: c++, gsoap

I am new to GSOAP, so might be missing something obvious here.
But I really couldn't find its solution in GSOAP documentations.

I need to know, how do I silently ignore an unknown node in my xml in GSOAP without affecting other nodes.

For example: I have below class

```
class gsoap_ex
{
int foo;
char bar;    
}
```

and below XML for it:

```
<gsoap_ex>
<foo>foo_value</foo>
<unknown>unknown_value</unknown>
<bar>bar_value</bar> 
</gsoap_ex>
```

As of now, my gsoap parses the xml till it reaches the unknown node, after that it returns without further parsing it.

```
print_after_parsing(gsoap_ex *obj)
{
cout<<obj->foo;
cout<<obj->bar;
}
```

So in my above function it shows the value of foo but value of bar is not set.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure gSOAP to provide a function pointer to deal with unknown elements, and have your function decide what to do with it.

The https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapfaq.html page discusses handling unknown data. The first part of the paragraph is about detecting unexpected data so that you can figure out what to do about the problem; it seems you've already got that covered, so I've just included the sections detailing how to change the behavior of gSOAP.

> **My code appears to ignore data when receiving SOAP/XML messages. How can I detect unrecognized element tags at run time and let my
>   application fault?**
>
> ...
>
> Another way to control the dropping of unknown elements is to define
>   the fignore callback. For example:
>
> ```
> { 
>     struct soap soap;   
>     soap_init(&soap);   
>     soap.fignore = mustmatch; // overwrite default callback   
>     ...
>     soap_done(&soap); // reset callbacks 
> } 
>
> int mustmatch(struct soap *soap, const char *tag) { 
>     return SOAP_TAG_MISMATCH; // every tag must be handled 
> }
> ```
>
> The tag parameter contains the offending tag name. You can also
>   selectively return a fault:
>
> ```
> int mustmatch(struct soap *soap, const char *tag) { 
>
>     // all tags in namespace "ns" that start with "login" are optional
>     if (soap_match_tag(soap, tag, "ns:login*"))   
>         return SOAP_OK;   
>
>     // every other tag must be understood (handled)
>     return SOAP_TAG_MISMATCH;
> }
> ```

Presumably, you'd want to write such a callback that returns `SOAP_OK` for your unexpected data.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but somehow it doesn't work for me. My `mustmatch` function which I assigned to `soap->fignore` never gets hit, so the default behavior continues.

Comment: @foobar - Have you tied setting `soap_set_imode(&soap, SOAP_XML_STRICT)`?

Comment: Below are my settings:
`m_soap.namespaces = namespaces;
soap_init2(&m_soap, SOAP_XML_TREE, SOAP_XML_TREE | SOAP_XML_IGNORENS);
m_soap.fignore = must_match;
soap_set_imode(&m_soap, SOAP_XML_TREE | SOAP_XML_IGNORENS);
soap_imode(&m_soap, SOAP_XML_TREE);`

Comment: @foobar - I don't see SOAP_XML_STRICT in there, the faq I linked seems to indicate that is what you need in order to use `fignore`.

Comment: it doesnt work even after doing `soap_set_imode(&soap,SOAP_XML_STRICT)` is there anyother setting I need to do?

Comment: Do your gsoap header files define `//gsoap` namespace declarations? Why do you have IGNORENS turned on? Why do you assign to `m_soap.namespace` before calling `soap_init`? Why do you set each `imode` and `omode` multiple times (the `soap_init2` call should be enough)? It seems that with proper namespace declarations and processing, this should do something - either work, call your `fignore` handler, or throw an exception. Reading between the lines of the FAQ, I get the impression that improper or incomplete namespace handling could be part of the problem.